# Fragmented packets on Red Hat Linux

Tags: linux, redhat, fragmentation

Our application runs on Red Hat Linux 8.0 3.2-7,  Linux kernel version 2.4.32.
We've found that the OS does not know how to handle fragmented packets.  When receiving a large amount of fragmented packets, the application running on the OS, crashes due to out-of-memory.
Does anyone know of a solution? or can refer me to a Linux version that resolves this issue?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

That doesn't sound too good. Can you post the crash messages? Are you running iptables or any OS-level firewall on the system?

Of course, the right thing is to upgrade from RedHat 8.0. That OS was end-of-lifed in 2003.